# LTC2852HDD Transceiver defect when the polarity is change

Tags: transceiver

I have been unsing the above transceiver for our application.  I have discover that when I turn the polarity of this device, the Transceiver does  not work anymore or is defect, because taking back in right polarity, he does not work anymore.

Have been reading many on the topic, I am still wondering, why the transceiver is defect. But I am looking now for solution for the problem.

Will it be possible to just a schottky diode on the line? But I will get a voltage drop and I am afraid that this will lead the Transceiver in an unknown domain.
[image]

Here is DATA1+', DATA1-'  and DATA2+', DATA2-' are at the input connector and
DATA1+, DATA1- and DATA2+ and DATA2- at the output connector.

the error occurs when the connector of input is plug to output.

The pin mapping of the connector are as quoted above.

Please of suggestion.

thanks

Comment: Show us a schematic, without a schematic we can only guess. Obviously by "turning the polarity of the device" you are violating the **Absolute maximum ratings** of the LTC2852 and that will damage it.

Comment: The AB,YZ inputs have failsafe feature that is guaranteed to work for inputs
spanning the entire common mode range of –7V to 12V . Did you exceed this? Is your soldering iron and bench ESD safe?

Comment: I did not exceed the common range value.my bench ESD and soldering iron are safe or otherwise soldering is through reflow and the working place are all ESD safe.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie,  the driver output Y and Zmaximum rating can be violated since his common mode output voltage is 3V and this output is then use as input by reverse, knowing that the common mode output of A and B is 12V.         could this be the issue? if yes how could I solve it? it is also stipulated that the driver has an overvoltage protection on the Y and z output.